# ¿Como seleccionar nodo desde cadena con formato XML en VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net

Hola tengo la siguiente cadena con formato XML en una variable de tipo String (Texto Plano) y necesitó leer desde el Nodo Terceros su hijo Tercero:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GuardarTercero xmlns="http://1.1.1.1/WebService/Servicios/Servicios.asmx">
      <NroEmpresa>1234</NroEmpresa>
      <AnoIngreso>2022</AnoIngreso>
      <MesIngreso>1</MesIngreso>
      <DiaIngreso>1</DiaIngreso>
      <Datos><Terceros><Tercero><Identificacion>5188296</Identificacion><Sucursal>0</Sucursal><UsaSucursal>0</UsaSucursal><Nombre>Efrain Mejias</Nombre><Tipo>1</Tipo><Contacto>efrain2020@gmail.com</Contacto><Direccion>CARRERA DE LA VIDA</Direccion><Telefono1>1111</Telefono1><Email>efrain2020@gmail.com</Email><Estado>1</Estado><CodigoPais>1</CodigoPais><CodigoCiudad>1</CodigoCiudad><TipoIdentificacionTributaria>1</TipoIdentificacionTributaria><ClasificacionTributaria></ClasificacionTributaria><Cliente ListaPrecio = "0" Calificacion = "0" FormaDePago = "0"Vendedor = "0" Cobrador = "0"></Cliente><Proveedor Calificacion = "0" FormaDePago = "0"></Proveedor><CodigoActEconomica></CodigoActEconomica><TipoPersonaJuridica></TipoPersonaJuridica ><UsaAgenteRetenedor></UsaAgenteRetenedor><BeneficiarioRteIVA></BeneficiarioRteIVA><AgenteReteIca></AgenteReteIca><Declarante></Declarante><UsaRetencion></UsaRetencion><UsaRazonSocial></UsaRazonSocial><Telefono2></Telefono2><Telefono3></Telefono3><Fax></Fax><Telefono3></Telefono3><PrimerApellido>Mejias</PrimerApellido><SegundoApellido>Castillo</SegundoApellido><PrimerNombre>Efrain</PrimerNombre><SegundoNombre>Emilio</SegundoNombre></Tercero></Terceros></Datos>
    </GuardarTercero>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Eso es SOAP que en un .net se lee casi automático.  O tú tienes solo ese XML y quieres leerlo a pulso??

Comment: Me uno al comentario de @Yussef. Deberias indicar si tienes el texto plano del XML o si lo lees a traves de algun mecanismo como llamada del webservice

Comment: Hola Yussef , Jose A. Fernandez ... tengo la siguiente cadena en una variable de tipo String  es decir el texto plano del XML